How to restart a script when crashed in Startup Applications in Ubuntu 22.04.4
Running a Python script which sends sms if Frigate/mqtt issued an event trigger. The script is added to Startup Applications program in Ubuntu 20.04.4 successfully. If and when the Python script crashes, will it be restarted by Startup Applications program? If not, how can I get it restarted once crashed?

Error detection and correction should be done in the Python script, or a simple wrapper around your Python script. Why put up with a Python script that "crashes"?

Use a try: exception block in Python and handle your error in the exception block. Apps and scripts are responsible for error handling, not the OS it is running in.
